# spring amqp ConfirmCallback CorrelationData is null sometimes

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I enable publish confirm, and call RabbitTemplate send method with CorrelationData. But when i get CorrelationData in ConfirmCallback, sometimes CorrelationData is null and ack is true. I must add judgement Correlation!=null.

Is it a normal behavior in spring amqp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you configure the `RabbitTemplate` to support confirms you have to provide correlation data.

If you invoke a `send` method with no correlation data parameter or with a `null` argument, you will get `null` in the callback.

The intention is that, if you want confirmations, you need to provide correlation data for every send (so you can determine which send the confirmation is for).

Comment: every send has correlationdata and not null,but sometimes get null,seems confirmcallback invoke more times than send

Comment: What version of Spring AMQP? There have been a few fixes in this area (although I don't specifically remember this one). The current release is 1.5.1.RELEASE. If you still see problems with that version, please [open a JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP).

Comment: Please ensure that you definitely provided correlation data and attach a debug log that exhibits the problem to a JIRA issue.

Comment: In addition it would be great to have some simple test-case to reproduce or to play, at least.

Comment: We have a stress test for this functionality - I just [patched the test](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-amqp/blob/SO33414770/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplatePublisherCallbacksIntegrationTests.java#L149) to stress it even further (100k messages across 100 threads) and to detect extra acks and/or nulls and it passes just fine. Perhaps you are seeing this under some abnormal condition?

Comment: sorry, it is my mistake. i use the same rabbittemplate for mock consumer and not send correlationdata